# How to hide and show buttons on click of that in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 4 buttons.

- Initially only one button will be displayed and remaining three should get hide.

**I done the scenario in the example fiddle, but that code is not proper. I want to use ternary operator and need to simplify using toggle.**

For example 4 buttons are,

1. first
2. Second
3. Third
4. Fourth

- It is like two different toggle buttons. I can use ternary operator.
- When I click the first button, I need to show "second and Third" buttons and I need to hide the first button. So now only second and third button should show. If I click again the second button i need to show the first button and i need to hide the second and third button.
- After click on 3rd button, i need to hide the third button and need to show the fourth button. Again if i click 4th button it should change as third button.

Please check the below example snippet.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.showFirst = true;
  $scope.showSecond = false;
  $scope.showThird = false;
  $scope.showFourth = false;

  $scope.toggle1 = function() {
    $scope.showFirst = false;
    $scope.showSecond = true;
    $scope.showThird = true;
    $scope.showFourth = false;
  };
  $scope.toggle2 = function() {
    $scope.showFirst = true;
    $scope.showSecond = false;
    $scope.showThird = false;
    $scope.showFourth = false;
  };
  $scope.toggle3 = function() {
    $scope.showFirst = false;
    $scope.showSecond = true;
    $scope.showThird = false;
    $scope.showFourth = true;
  };
  $scope.toggle4 = function() {
    $scope.showFirst = false;
    $scope.showSecond = false;
    $scope.showThird = true;
    $scope.showFourth = false;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-show="showFourth" ng-click="toggle4()">test 4</button>
  <button ng-show="showThird" ng-click="toggle3()">test 3</button>
  <button ng-show="showSecond" ng-click="toggle2()">test 2</button>
  <button ng-show="showFirst" ng-click="toggle1()">test 1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by storing which buttons you'd like to show in an array:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.showButtons = [0];

  $scope.toggle1 = function() {
    $scope.showButtons = [1, 2];
  };
  $scope.toggle2 = function() {
    $scope.showButtons = [0];
  };
  $scope.toggle3 = function() {
    $scope.showButtons = [1, 3];
  };
  $scope.toggle4 = function() {
    $scope.showButtons = [2];
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-show="showButtons.includes(3)" ng-click="toggle4()">test 4</button>
  <button ng-show="showButtons.includes(2)" ng-click="toggle3()">test 3</button>
  <button ng-show="showButtons.includes(1)" ng-click="toggle2()">test 2</button>
  <button ng-show="showButtons.includes(0)" ng-click="toggle1()">test 1</button>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also store the toggle functions inside an array of objects and use it with `ng-repeat`:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.buttons = [
    {
      id: 'test 1',
      fn: function() {
        showButtons([1, 2]);
      },
      show: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'test 2',
      fn: function() {
        showButtons([0]);
      },
      show: false,
    },
    {
      id: 'test 3',
      fn: function() {
        showButtons([1, 3]);
      },
      show: false,
    },
    {
      id: 'test 4',
      fn: function() {
        showButtons([2]);
      },
      show: false,
    },
  ];

  function showButtons(show) {
    $scope.buttons.forEach(function(btn, i) {
      btn.show = show.includes(i);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-show="button.show" ng-click="button.fn()">
    {{button.id}}
  </button>
</div>
```